# is it “a lesson to all of us” or “a lesson for all of us”?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Which one is the correct one to use? I'm confused when to use "to" or "for"

> 1. This is a lesson **to** all of us
> 2. This is a lesson **for** all of us.

Google Books shows [8,940 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lesson%20to%20all%20of%20us%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4rYHD25TYAhVF6KQKHSYlAeoQ_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=615) for "lesson to all of us"
while it shows [13,800 results](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=615&tbm=bks&ei=V084WpeQKcyykwXF-Zn4BQ&q=%22lesson%20for%20all%20of%20us%22&oq=%22lesson%20for%20all%20of%20us%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...72210.74113.0.75941.5.5.0.0.0.0.236.707.0j4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.inwl5YKyJsE) for "lesson for all of us"

Comment: Hello, welcome to ELU. This site actually requires questions to be thoroughly researched and the results of such research to be included in your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You are also highly encouraged to ask questions about basic/elementary English grammar on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Clare It seems a fair enough question to me. Either "to" or "for" are possible - with differently nuanced meanings. Even native speakers may have difficulty explaining the difference, as I am finding. It is a good question for the site, in my view.

Comment: What is the meaning, in other words, of the lesson?  That might help figure out which preposition would be best.

Comment: @WS2 (1) because a native speaker does not find it easy to explain the difference does not make a question a good one for this site (2) questions which indicate absolutely no research are not good questions for this site (it is no longer 2014)

Comment: @Clare What sort of research do you recommend here?

Comment: [To vs for](http://www.englishandculture.com/blog/bid/95563/Quick-English-Grammar-Tip-To-Versus-For)

Comment: @WS2 (1) actually read [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (2) search this site for [to or for](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=To+or+for+) (3) search the Internet for the difference between to and for (4) consult an EFL/ESL tutor/teacher.... ***Also*** give sufficient context in the question itself (another thing this one lacks)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I've read that, but I'm not sure there is enough there to answer the OP. A "lesson" can be either something that is delivered (to) or something  done to benefit you (for). But I think you should only use "for" if the lesson was formally intended  to be for the person's benefit. "Let that be a lesson to you", is where something unintended served as a useful lesson.

Comment: @WS2 It goes back to what the OP wanted to communicate.  The correct sense depends on the intended sense (i.e. lesson delivered to us all vs. a lesson benefiting us all).

Comment: Em E, It ***is*** a good question though it needs some research effort and some context.  I suggest that you edit and add what the community feels is lacking.  Otherwise it's doomed to be closed as off topic.

Comment: And "lesson to us all" yields 14,100 results!

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to the site and unfamiliar with the rules of this forum. I was reading an article on the web yesterday re. Kennesaw cheerleaders and came across a statement that I found to be puzzling: “The KSU cheerleaders will go down in civil rights history,” said Susan Raines, who is a professor of conflict management at the school. “What little power they had made a difference, and that should be a <b> lesson to all of us </b>. I was under the impression that the correct way was lesson for all of us and sought for clarification on this forum. Thank you so much for all your comments!

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer an opinion although it is not about the correctness of the utterances.  Both are grammatical and quite clear.   The difference in my opinion is that "for" has an inclusive and cooperative feeling to it that "to" does not.  If I were trying to get a group of people to act cooperatively I would use "for".  In my opinion, it is simply a matter of connotation, not denotation or correctness.

Comment: Yes, it's pragmatics. The use of to' is more incisive, clinical ... approaching judgemental. 'Let this be a lesson _to_ you!'

Answer (score -1):

Both forms are grammatical, but 'for' is weaker -- meaning that some of us (the intended recipients) may not have gotten it yet.